# Как добавить стандартную кнопку Google+ Sing-In

Tags: java, android, зависимости

Я установил Google Play Services в SDK, после чего добавил в свой 'Layout' код гугл кнопки

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
    android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

и мне показывает

```
 Rendering Problems The following classes could not be found:
- com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton (Fix Build Path, Create Class)
 Tip: Try to build the project.
```

Говорят вроде есть баг в Google Play Services (5.0) и нужно понизить версию и добавить в раздел dependencies

```
dependencies{
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.4.52'
...
}
```

Я новичок в этом можете подсказать где найти этот раздел и правильно ли я нашел решение проблемы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

на самом деле добавлена не правильная 'dependency' 
нужно добавить этот

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

черная стрелочка это файл в который нужно вставить

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.4.52'`

красная стрелочка это место куда именно нужно вставить

Comment: Я вставил эту строчку так как показано на слайде, и еще раз зделал grade и мне показало следующие ошибки  /home/aleksey/Parks/parksClientNew/ParksClient/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services/4.4.52/res/values/wallet_colors.xml
Error:(2) Attribute "theme" has already been defined
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/aleksey/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAIL

Comment: попробуй переписать зависимости как на скрине который я тебе скинул.
и еще у тебя ошибка в темах. если ты создавал темы сам то попробуй их удалить и запустить с стандартными темами

Comment: Я добавил к себе не эту строчку compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.4.52' , а вот эту compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'   и вроде нет ошибок. Но все равно когда я добавляю код кнопки мне показывает такую ошибку                                                                                                     Rendering Problems The following classes could not be found:
- com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton (Fix Build Path, Create Class)
 Tip: Try to build the project.     Я попробовал все что предлагает студия но кнопка так и не появилась